# Java SWT DateTime - Get Selection?

Tags: java, datetime, swt, selection

I've got a DateTime (SWT.TIME) and want to know if the hours or minutes or seconds are selected.
I would like to get this information because I want that the User can scroll the mouse wheel in order to change the selected values accordingly.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any way to get the selected element of the DateTime Control. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

[`DateTime`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FDateTime.html) provides many methods for getting the selected date. Like `getHours`, `getMinutes`, `getDay`, and so on. It's unclear to me what's your exact question, but appropiate setters are there as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. But the user can *select* parts of the DateTime control (which includes a kind of text field). I want to get information about which part the user selected.